# compressing images using grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed node,npm,and then grunt.Then,I tried compressing the images writing the following code in the Gruntfile.Js:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
responsive_images: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      engine: 'im',
      sizes: [{

        width:800 ,
        suffix:'_large_1x' ,
        quality: 30

      }]
    },
```

and the img in my html file is as follows :

```
<img src="images_src/still_life-800_large_1x.jpg">
```

however,when i refreshed the web page ,i checked the "network" in the developer's tools and the picture "failed to response data"!